# Adding float column to TimestampType column (seconds+miliseconds)

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, hiveql

I am trying to add a float column to a TimestampType column in pyspark, but there does not seem to be a way to do this while maintaining the fractional seconds. example of float_seconds is 19.702300786972046, example of timestamp is 2021-06-17 04:31:32.48761

what I want:

```
calculated_df = beginning_df.withColumn("calculated_column", float_seconds_col + TimestampType_col)
```

I have tried the following methods, but neither completely solves the problem:

#method 1 adds a single time, but cannot be used to add an entire column to the timestamp column.

```
calculated_df = beginning_df.withColumn("calculated_column",col("TimestampType_col") + F.expr('INTERVAL 19.702300786 seconds'))
```

#method 2 converts the float column to unixtime, but cuts off the decimals (which are important)

```
timestamp_seconds = beginning_df.select(from_unixtime("float_seconds"))
```

[Image of the two columns in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21rrD.png)

Comment: please let me know if  the following answer helps

Comment: What is the expected result based on your example.  Is it `2021-06-17 04:31:52.189911`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it using a UDF as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, FloatType, TimestampType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredStreamTesting") \
    .getOrCreate()
schema = (StructType([
    StructField('dt', TimestampType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('sec', FloatType(), nullable=True),
]))

item1 = {
    "dt": datetime.fromtimestamp(1611859271.516),
    "sec": 19.702300786,
}
item2 = {
    "dt": datetime.fromtimestamp(1611859271.517),
    "sec": 19.702300787,
}

item3 = {
    "dt": datetime.fromtimestamp(1611859271.518),
    "sec": 19.702300788,
}

df = spark.createDataFrame([item1, item2, item3], schema=schema)

df.printSchema()


@udf(returnType=TimestampType())
def add_time(dt, sec):
    return dt + timedelta(seconds=sec)


df = df.withColumn("new_dt", add_time(col("dt"), col("sec")))
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would this be scalable to very very large datasets?

Comment: IMO, this should be scalable, also you can a run a profiling.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp data type supports nanoseconds (max 9 digits precision). Your float_seconds_col has precision > 9 digits (15 in your example, it is femto-seconds), it will be lost if converted to Timestamp anyway.

Plain vanilla Hive:

```
select 
      timestamp(cast(concat(cast(unix_timestamp(TimestampType_col) as string), --seconds
                            '.', 
                            regexp_extract(TimestampType_col,'\\.(\\d+)$')) --fractional
                     as decimal (30, 15) 
                   ) + float_seconds_col --round this value to nanos to get better timestamp conversion (round(float_seconds_col,9))
               ) as result --max precision is 9 (nanoseconds)
       
from
(
select 19.702300786972046                     float_seconds_col,
       timestamp('2021-06-17 04:31:32.48761') TimestampType_col
) s
```

Result:

```
2021-06-17 04:31:52.189910786
```